# Get URL from background-image property by regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need get a URL by regular expression from a string. My code:

```php
$mystring = file_get_contents($urlstr);
preg_match('/background-image: url\(\\\'\/\/(.*png)|background-image:url\(\\\'\/\/(.*jpg)|background-image: url\((.*jpeg)|background-image: url\(\\\'\/\/(.*gif)/', $mystring, $A);
$prw = 'http://'.end($A);
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a handful of examples? Seeing what the input is (and what you expect the captured output to be) would help quite a bit.

Comment: You should use sabberworm css parser (https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser/tree/master/lib/Sabberworm/CSS) to extract the `background-image` property values (in particular you will not have quotes or spaces problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
background-image:[ ]?url\(['"]?(.*?\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif))
```

which will match the URLS found on [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tH4gP9/1) example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the regular expression you need is.

```
\background\-image:\surl\((.*(jpg|png|gif|jpeg))\
```

You forgot the escape the - in your original regular expression, and you didn't need to enter the full match four times when you could just do an or on the extensions.

Note that you could also put some optional features in there to ensure you catch all of the background-image declarations, such as extra whitespace, etc.